# Any way to animate changing UIStatusBarStyle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios6

Just wondering if there's any way to animate changing `UIStatusBarStyle` in iOS 6. Currently when you change the status bar style via `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:style]` the change occurs instantaneously. It would be nice if the change could animate in (i.e., fade in).

On a tangential note, I've noticed that it's possible to place views on top of the status bar even in iOS 6, but I haven't figured out how to do that. Would this help at all in creating a more fluid transition between status bar styles?

Comment: UIWindow by the way is how you add stuff ontop of status bars. with style type at status window and `makeKeyAndVisible`

Answer (score 2):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:style animated:YES];`

To adjust the speed of the animation look at Duncan C's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26112173/2057171) and don't forget to up vote his answer too! https://stackoverflow.com/a/26112173/2057171

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarStyle:animated:

Comment: For iOS 2.0 and later - import UIKit (there by default in xCode)

Comment: Quick second question: Any way to adjust the animation speed of `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:style animated:animated]`? Specifically, to speed it up a little bit?

Comment: @KenM.Haggerty you might be able to do something with the `CATransaction`. Not sure of the specifics, but that would be a good place to start.

Comment: That's the correct answer. (Voted) To the OP, you should accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your follow-on question about changing the animation duration, try this:

Try enclosing the call to setStatusBarStyle:animated: in a CATransaction. It would look like this:

```
//Create a transaction group that has it's own duration
[CATransaction begin];

//Set the duration for this animation group
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration: .5];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:style animated:YES];

[CATransaction commit];
```